# How to show live streaming camera videos in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, opencv, django-rest-framework

I am building a application in django rest framework and frontend in react i want to shows streaming of multiple live camera into browsers there is any way how we can achieve it using openCV or how we can genrate response with stream of bytes in django rest framework

Comment: no. OpenCV is for computer vision, not for moving video around a network. use the right library for the right job.

Comment: if you would use `Flask` then you would find many examples how to send it as many images JPG (`motion-jpg`, `mjpeg`) and browser will automatically get next images. And it needs `OpenCV` only to get images from camera (frame after frame) because rest has to do `Flask`. In `Django`  you can also use `OpenCV` to read frame by frame from live camera and keep it in variable. And Django would have to send this frame like any other image. And browser may need to run loop to get new image (new frame) every few millisecond. I don't know if Django has method to send it as `motion-jpeg`.

Comment: if camera send stream using some URL then maybe it would be simpler to use this URL directly in HTML as `<video>`

Comment: Using Google `django mjpeg` I found project [https://github.com/carbofos/mjpeg-streaming-server](Python/Django MJPEG image push Axis IP camera simulation server) and it uses [Django.http.StreamingHttpResponse()](https://github.com/carbofos/mjpeg-streaming-server/blob/master/mjpeg/views.py#L50) to send stream. And similar to `Flask` it uses loop with `yield` to send frame after frame.

Comment: [How to stream .webm or .mjpeg from Python Django server? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73056469/how-to-stream-webm-or-mjpeg-from-python-django-server)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz there are any library is available ?? because i read frame from opencv then perform some machine learning task and then after that i want to send this frame to my frontend this is actual secenrio

Comment: @furas i see many example but i still able to work with single camera in production it may 10 15 camera or more

Comment: there is possible way to use Django channels with celery ???

Comment: every camera may need to run `opencv` in separated thread and create separated variable with image. And django will need separated URL for ever camera (or at least url with different parameters to recognize which webcam to stream). I never tried this with Django. I only did it with local GUI (tkinter)  to display many streams from cameras, web pages, local files: [furas/python-cv2-streams-viewer](https://github.com/furas/python-cv2-streams-viewer)

Comment: @furas many many thanks because i get a way to solve it thanks for your reply it really very helpful for me

Comment: @MuhammadArshad have you managed to solve it using ```Django``` and ```ReactJS```? If yes, please guide me.. I'm facing a similar issue. I have done this on GUI using PyQt but now the company wants me to display it on web browser.

Comment: @Voldemort I used node js to shows live camera streaming in web which is very effective for our use I suggest you if it is possible kindly you can used Node js for creating streaming you camera feed...